# Burger menu back to 3 links after menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hamburger-menu

I have a burger icon that when clicked turns into an X. When clicked again turns back into the 3 lines. I have it working so when the links are clicked the menu goes away, but the burger menu doesn't return back to 3 lines. Nothing I have tried is working. Here is what I have.

```
var burgerIcon = $('.burger-icon');

function toggleBurger(){
    burgerIcon.click(function(){
        if(burgerIcon.hasClass("is-active") === true)
        {
            burgerIcon.removeClass("is-active");
            //console.log("remove");
        }
        else
        {
            burgerIcon.addClass("is-active");
            //console.log("add");
        }
    });
}

toggleBurger();

$('.toggle-nav').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav'); 
    return false;
});

$('nav ul li > a').click(function(){
    //console.log("clicked");;
    $('body').trigger( "click" );
    burgerIcon.trigger( "click" );
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
                        <li data-magellan-arrival="work">
                            <a href="#work" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Work</a>
                        </li>

                        <li data-magellan-arrival="about">
                            <a href="#about" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">About</a>
                        </li>

                        <li data-magellan-arrival="shadow">
                            <a href="#shadow" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Shadow CC</a>
                        </li>

                        <li data-magellan-arrival="clients">
                            <a href="#clients" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Clients</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to explain: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qe38m0t9/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle sample

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you saying that when clicking a link (an `<a>` tag) that you want `.c-hamburger` to have its `is-active` class removed? Why not just put that in the click function?

Comment: Here is a fiddle that give you an idea.. you can click on the burger icon, and you can also click again to close it. If you click on a link, the menu goes away but the burger icon stays open
https://jsfiddle.net/qe38m0t9/

Comment: was this line supposed to be a conditional? or an assignment?  Please clarify: `(this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
`

Comment: I was using this as a starting point for the burger animation. That is where I got the script from.http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons

Comment: fiddle was also updated and simplified

Comment: OK so to answer my own question, it is a ternary used as an if/else statement and is not supposed to be something else.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using jQuery in your code you can leverage that and then really ALL you need I believe is this:

```
$('nav ul li > a,.c-hamburger').click(function () {
    console.log("clicked");
    $('body').toggleClass('show-nav');
    if ($('body').hasClass('show-nav')) {
        $('.c-hamburger').addClass("is-active");
    } else {
        $('.c-hamburger').removeClass("is-active");
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qe38m0t9/2/

NOTE: this uses two selectors, one for the "hamburger" thing and another for the menu separated by a comma then does the same thing depending upon which is clicked.